# how to save the filter image into the gallery

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gallery, android-bitmap

In my application I have taken image from gallery and I have apply the filter options on that image after that again I have to save that image into the  gallery, But I can save only the image as normal image itself, but the filter image methods are not saved.

In that image I have used setOnLongClickListener method if I press on the image the list menu will be displayed we can select the filter option than we can save,But this image filter options not saved into the gallery.

Comment: Show your code in order to understand others

Comment: which code I want to show.